# how to change default editor for latex when compiling in the bash?

Tags: compiling, emacs, editors, bash

When you compile a latex file in bash (e.g., via a makefile), if latex encounters an error it stops for you to enter a command, for example `R` to continue running or `Q` to run quietly. Entering `E` calls the `editor` to fix the error, which is `vim` by default. How can I change this default to `emacs`?

From a previous post:

```
export TEXEDIT="emacs +%d %s"
```

Comment: On unix, it should be a matter of setting the environment variable EDITOR=emacs. If you're on windows, I haven't a clue. (But since you say bash, I assume it's unix …)

Comment: I assumed the same but tt seems it is the environment variable `TEXEDIT`